# Regarding Limit/continuity/convergence

Tags: limits, continuity, uniform-convergence

let $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1-nx&\text{when }x\in[0,1/n]\\0&\text{when }x\in [1/n,1]\end{cases}$$
Which of the following is correct?

1. $\lim_{ n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ defines a continuous function on $[0,1]$
2. $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$
3. $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$
4. $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ exists for all $x\in[0,1]$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MahtJax (see FAQ). regards

Comment: fn(0)=1 and fn(1)=0, so definitely it's not uniform convergence and neither lim n->infinity fn(x)=0 for all x. so, we are left with 'a' and 'd' options.

Comment: @Ramit Yes. Are you sure that $1/n$ is included on both parts of the piecewise definition? If yes, continuity is apparent.

Comment: @TorstenHĕrculĕCärlemän yes, 1/n is there in both parts. closed bracket, not open. but the answer is 'd' as per the key that I am checking.

Comment: @Hagen- thanks for editing my question.

Comment: @Ramit I have made a mistake. Still, Let us use intuition to verify our answers, not some premade keys, mon cher ami!

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed simply for being homework - the OP is interacting with the comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let denote $\displaystyle f=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$.

For $x=0$ we have $f_n(0)=1,\quad\forall n>0$ so $f(0)=1$.

For $x>0$ there's $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n}\leq x,\quad \forall n\geq N$ so $f_n(x)=0\quad \forall n\geq N$ and then $f(x)=0$ so we conclude:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}\\
1&\text{if}\ x=0\\
0&\text{if}\ 0<x\leq1
\end{array}\right.$$

Now can you answer the questions?

> It's clear that $f$ isn't continuous at $0$ so options 1. and 2. are false and $f(0)=1$ so also option 3. isn't true and since $f(x)$ exists for all $x\in[0,1]$ so option 4. is true.

Comment: thanks @Sami for this part. But I am yet not able to tick the correct option. I am sensing that the limit doesn't exist on 0, since function value and right limit don't match. so it's not continuous. very obviously, m thinking wrong. looks like m not clear on continuity. i'll try to refer some book. but i'll appreciate if u can provide some quick help.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Limit at $0$ of what?

Comment: lim n->infinity f(0)=1
lim n->infinity f(0.5)=0
lim n->infinity f(1)=0
clearly, limit exits for all. but why the discontinuity? I wish u could explain. thanks.

Comment: You can see that $f$ isn't continuous at $0$ since $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=1\neq f(0)=0$ and since the functions $f_n$ are continuous and their pointwise limit $f$ isn't continuous so the convergence isn't uniform.

Comment: understood. thanks a ton @Sami

Comment: You're welcome.